# Vuejs - Svgs partially missing once a third is added

Tags: css, vue.js, svg, flexbox

Not really sure how to ask this question to be honest, but recently I've started using VueJS and it's incredible!
That being said, with all the learning of Vue, I perhaps have lost a bit of my CSS skills; particularly when it comes to flex. I don't recall ever having this issue previously, but once I added a third SVG to my page, the two previous almost completely disappear, but the newest is fully visible.

Any ideas of what the heck could actually be happening here?
I'm not using SVG loader or anything, but rather a v-else-if to show svgs based on names; perhaps that's the issue? (though if that were, the two previously shown were fine until I added the third.)

Cheers!

NOTE: I'm not adding the SVG code, since I didn't want to have too much code showing in this question, but it's a simple hamburger menu svg, a search svg and the top nav stuff for an iphone.
[image: Weird SVG Bug]

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container">
      <top-nav-bar></top-nav-bar>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TopNavBar from './components/molecules/TopNavBar.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { TopNavBar },
}
</script>

<style lang="sass">
#app
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
  text-align: center
  color: #2c3e50

.container
  position: relative
  margin: 0 auto
  border: 2px solid black
  background-color: white
  border-radius: 40px
  width: 414px
  height: 896px
</style>
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <icons name="nav-info" />
    <icons name="hamburger" />
    <icons name="search" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Icons from '../atoms/Icons.vue'

export default {
  components: { Icons },
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
.container
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  align-items: center

  margin: 0
</style>
```

Comment: My guess would be that the SVG files have duplicate ids i.e. one file contains id="x" but so does another.

Comment: @RobertLongson Interesting. You'd think that it would cancel out or override whatever it's repeating. The like 20% of the svg that still shows makes me think that something is overlaid.